# Can ping a local server IP but can't browse a site into the server

Tags: browser, ip, ping

I have a server connected to the network with the ip 192.168.xxx.xxx. I can ping the ip but when i try to access from the browser to the server's localhost, obviusly with the IP, i can't.

What is wrong??

UPDATE!!

There was a network error... not configuration!! Thanks for help! Problem solved!

Comment: There was a problem with the network... not problem with the configuration.

Comment: What was the problem exactly??

Answer (score 0):

Check if the port you are trying to connect is open. If it is not, you have to bring up the port first, Example: if you are trying to run an app from tomcat, start tomcat first,

Comment: how can i check what port i'm using? i'm trying to access from firefox.

Comment: Can you share the url you are using in browser

Comment: it's an internal server. The server has an ip 192.168.100.47... With a pc in the same network (192.168.100.20) i can access without problems, but when my pc is in the network 192.168.101.37, i can ping but can't view the sites inside the localhost of the server. The network thes the server is connected has access to all the networks because others servers are configured with that network but this server can't show his localhost... I don't understand why i can ping and can't browse the localhost in network "A" but can ping and can't browse in the network "B" when other servers can do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons why this would happen:

1. The server is not set up to receive incoming connections. Check your firewall settings
2. The server isn't publicly visible (Meaning the server will appear to a ping, but all the ports are closed
3. The server isn't able to make outbound connections, again, check the firewall.
4. To test ports, either port forward, or put the server in to a DMZ (All ports are open)
5. Manually attempt a file transfer or another service by using `ftp <IP of server>:<port number eg 21)` or an SSH tunnel. If the FTP passes, then the HTTP port of the server may be down (port 80/8080).
6. Verify the router interconnecting your PC and the server isn't restricting local peer crosstalk.